# Как заменить GetKeyDown на UI кнопку

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Как сделать мне прыжок через кнопку UI где вызывается метод Jump. На кнопку стоит этот метод. Так вот как мне GetKeydown поменять управление на UI кнопку??? помогите пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, если по нажатию на UI-кнопку вызывается этот метод, то почему бы просто не убрать эту проверку? (И не вызывать метод в других ситуациях, конечно)

Comment: Так-же большая просьба прикладывать код в виде текста, а не картинок

Answer (score 0):

Пусть вам на нажатие кнопки нужно выполнить функцию

```
public void Foo() {...}
```

Эта функция находится в каком-то скрипте `scTest`.

1. В компоненте `Button` кнопки нажимаем плюсик в окошке "OnClick".
2. Вешаем куда-нибудь (например на саму кнопку) скрипт `scTest`.
3. Указываем в окошко "OnClick" компонента `Button` вашей кнопки тот объект, на который вы повесили скрипт `scTest` в предыдущем пункте.
4. Из выпадающего списка справа выбираем скрипт `scTest`, затем выбираем функцию `Foo`. Она обязана быть публичной и иметь не более одного параметра.

Comment: Можно поподробнее я не понял

Comment: @Виталий https://you-hands.ru/2020/11/01/kak-polzovatsya-knopkami-v-unity/